# Unable to instantiate a GenericRecord in a Kafka Producer for streaming avro to a topic

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to create a Java producer that streams Avro to a kafka topic.
I've tried to reproduce the example that is presented in [Confluent's official documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html)

but GenericRecord class -which is used as shown below- cannot be found.

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;

Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
Schema schema = parser.parse(userSchema);
GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
```

And here's the error reported:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Here's my `pom.xml` file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.giorgos.currencies</groupId>
  <artifactId>giorgos-fx_currencies</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>george-fx_currencies</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-repo</id>
            <name>Apache Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <properties>
        <kafka.version>0.8.2.1</kafka.version>
        <kafka.scala.version>2.10</kafka.scala.version>
        <confluent.version>4.0.0</confluent.version>
        <avro.version>1.7.6</avro.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>uber-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I was wondering whether wrong versions of avro/kafka/confluent are defined in the the `pom.xml` but I was not able to find the error. Also note that `mvn package` leads to a successful build without any errors reported.

**EDIT:**
I've tried to comment out these lines but a similar behaviour is observed for the following line:

```
KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
```

that gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer
    at com.giorgos.currencies.TestFX.main(TestFX.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

This is how I run the program:

```
java -cp target/giorgos-fx_currencies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.giorgos.currencies.TestFX command-line-argument
```

Comment: Confluent 4.0's Kafka version is 1.0.0 and Avro version is 1.8.2

Comment: In any case, you should be running the uber jar if you want Avro classes to be loaded

Comment: @cricket_007  I've set the versions to 1.0.0 and 1.8.2 for kafka and avro respectively but with no luck. See updated question. The same behaviour is observed for `KafkaProducer` when `GenericRecord` is commented out.

Comment: Not sure why you don't just clone / copy some example code https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer

Comment: You might want to verify your broker version before messing with the Kafka/Confluent versions, too

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried to follow this example, but I was not able to replace `LogLine` with my schema. And also I couldn't understand how to replace `JavaSessionize`.

Comment: @cricket_007 can you give some more details regarding broker version? How can I find out broker's version?

Comment: You talk to the person who installed the Kafka cluster... Or you go look at the download link you set it up with. If you're using the Confluent packages, look at the release notes for the version you've downloaded. Otherwise, you need to SSH to a broker and see what packages are installed. Regarding the LogLine, you need to learn about the Avro Maven Plugin and how to create an AVSC or AVDL file https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/specific-avro-producer/src/main/resources/avro

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using Confluent v4.0.0. 
Regarding the LogLine, I created a .avsc file that contains the required schema, but I was not able to get rid of `JavaSessionize`.

Comment: Overall, I think your issue is running the code incorrectly with the wrong classpath... You've not stated how you're running it, but those errors are not from an IDE. Without building a specific Avro class, you can in-line the schema as shown here. https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.3.0-post/kafka-clients/producer/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/producer/ProducerExample.java

Comment: Did you change the namespace of the AVSC? Then `mvn clean package`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the question and included how I execute the program.

Comment: As I said earlier, please use the uber jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the shade plugin, those classes are part of this file

```
target/uber-giorgos-fx_currencies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Use that to run your code.